# How to sort output based on a child directory

Tags: bash

I have a `grep` command which I'm using to get every file containing my string.

I would like to sort the output of the `grep` command using the first child directory of the output.

Example:

```
grep -Ril "mystring" --exclude-dir=myDir
dir1/customZ/dir1/myfile
dir1/customX/dir1/myfile
dir1/customY/dir1/myfile
dir1/customV/dir2/myfile
dir2/customB/dir2/myfile
dir2/customZZ/dir2/myfile
dir2/customX/dir2/myfile
```

I would like to sort my output on usin the 1st and 2nd directory `dir<value>/custom<VALUE>`.
Meaning my output would look something like:

```
dir1/customV/dir2/myfile
dir1/customX/dir1/myfile
dir1/customY/dir1/myfile
dir1/customZ/dir1/myfile
dir2/customB/dir2/myfile
dir2/customX/dir2/myfile
dir2/customZZ/dir2/myfile
```

Comment: If you type `man sort` you'll probably see that `sort` has a `-t` option to define the field separator (`/` in your case) and a `-k` option to define the sorting keys. So `grep -Ril "mystring" --exclude-dir=myDir | sort -t/ -k2,2` should do about what you want.

Comment: `How to grep` You want to grep or sort?

Comment: I'm aware of `sort`. I found the `-k` option, but I seem to overlooked the `-t` option that everyone has included in their solution.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: @N.J But you didn't update the discrepancy between "I would like to sort my output on the 2nd directory" (which everybody tried to solve) and the actually provided sample of the desired output (which is first sorted by the first directory, just then by the second, and could much more easily be achieved by just using `… | sort`, i.e. without any further arguments).

Comment: Qusetion and output should match@pmf?

Comment: @N.J Yes, it does now. But if you want to sort (as updated) by the first column, then by the second, why wasn't using just `sort` (i.e. without any arguments) any good?

Comment: @pmf I agree, `sort` is probably enough. Except for the last line, with the `customZZ` subdirectory. That still works, since `/` sorts before `Z`, but it's likely to fail for `customZ-Z`, since the `-` sorts before `/` (at least with ASCII and Unicode, which I think applies here).

Comment: @9769953 In my (Unicode) environment, `printf '%s\n' customZZ/dir customZ-Z/dir customZ/dir | sort` first yields `customZ/dir`, then `customZ-Z/dir`, then `customZZ/dir`. Isn't this the expected order?

Comment: @pmf Ok, I hadn't expected that. I copy-pasted your command into my terminal, and got the order of `customZ-Z/dir`, `customZ/dir`, `customZZ/dir`. That terminal has locale settings of `en_GB.UTF-8`. Using another machine/terminal with locale settings of `en_US.UTF-8`, I do get your output. But the first result is on macOS (BSD sort), the second on GNU/Linux. The manpage of GNU sort has the warning: "The locale specified by the environment affects sort order. Set `LC_ALL=C` to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values". So there's slighty more to it than just using plain sort.

Comment: @9769953 Agreed :) In my answer I have also already added the advice to use `-k1,2`.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This answers the original question with the wording `I would like to sort my output on the 2nd directory`. The wording was then changed to `I would like to sort my output on usin the 1st and 2nd directory`. For that, just change `-k2` to `-k1,2`, and/or have a look at the other responses.

---

You could use `sort` starting with field 2 `-k2`, using a slash as field delimiter `-t/`

```bash
… | sort -k2 -t/
```

```
dir2/customB/dir2/myfile
dir1/customV/dir2/myfile
dir1/customX/dir1/myfile
dir2/customX/dir2/myfile
dir1/customY/dir1/myfile
dir1/customZ/dir1/myfile
dir2/customZZ/dir2/myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output of `grep` to `sort -k`, using `/` as field separator:

```bash
$ grep -Ril "mystring" --exclude-dir=myDir | sort -k1,2 -t/
```

`-k1,2` tells `sort` to order the lines by the first field then order each group of lines having the same value for the first field (`dir1`, `dir2`) by the second field (`custom<VALUE>`).

`-t/` tells `sort` to use `/` as the field delimiter. The field numbering starts with `1`.

Type `man sort` in the terminal to read the documentation of `sort` or read it [online](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html).

Comment: Why the `-k1` ?

Comment: @9769953 to get the output posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sort`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) with a custom field seperator (`-t '/'`) and indicate you want to sort on the n'th field (`-k2,2`):

```
grep ... | sort -t '/' -k2,2
```

---

Output

```
dir2/customB/dir2/myfile
dir1/customV/dir2/myfile
dir1/customX/dir1/myfile
dir2/customX/dir2/myfile
dir1/customY/dir1/myfile
dir1/customZ/dir1/myfile
dir2/customZZ/dir2/myfile
```